# Why is a Flux<String> being collapsed into a single String when returned via ServerResponse, unless each String element is terminated with "\n"?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

While playing around with Spring Webflux and WebClient, I noted a behavior (demonstrated by the code below) when returning a *ServerResponse* containing a *`Flux<String>`*. Unless the *String* elements are terminated with a newline character, returning the *`Flux<String>`* via a *ServerResponse* appears to concatenate all *`Flux<String>`* elements into a single *String*. Can someone explain to me why I'm seeing this behavior, and what I am doing to cause it?

When each *String* element is terminated with a newline character, the *`Flux<String>`* is "returned as expected" via *ServerResponse*, and subscribing to the returned *`Flux<String>`* produces expected results. However, if viewed as simple JSON (via Postman), this also results in an extra, empty, String element being returned in the JSON body.

Console output showing described behavior...

1. The first listing of *String* elements occurs in *StringProducerHandler.getAll()*, and indicates the results of a *`Flux<String>`* containing 10 *String* elements, where the second occurrence of each *String* value is terminated with a newline character, resulting in a blank line being output.
2. The second listing of *String* elements occurs in *StringClient.getAll()*, and demonstrates how the original *String* elements that were not terminated with a newline character have been concatenated with the following element.

   2019-10-10 10:13:37.225  INFO 8748 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port(s): 8080
   2019-10-10 10:13:37.228  INFO 8748 --- [           main] c.example.fluxtest.FluxTestApplication   : Started FluxTestApplication in 1.271 seconds (JVM running for 1.796)

   *****  "Get" issued on http:/localhost:8080/StringClient/String
   StringClientHandler.getAll( ServerRequest )
   StringClient.getAll()
   StringProducerHandler.getAll( ServerRequest )
   ListElement-0
   ListElement-0

   ListElement-1
   ListElement-1

   ListElement-2
   ListElement-2

   ListElement-3
   ListElement-3

   ListElement-4
   ListElement-4

   ListElement-0ListElement-0 @ 1570727628948
   ListElement-1ListElement-1 @ 1570727628948
   ListElement-2ListElement-2 @ 1570727628948
   ListElement-3ListElement-3 @ 1570727628948
   ListElement-4ListElement-4 @ 1570727628949

Code to replicate this behavior is provided below...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FluxTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FluxTestApplication.class, args);
    }
}


@Configuration
public class StringClientRouter {
    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> clientRoutes(StringClientHandler requestHandler) {
        return nest(path("/StringClient"),
                nest(accept(APPLICATION_JSON),
                        RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.GET("/String"), requestHandler::getAll)));
    }
}


@Component
public class StringClientHandler {

    @Autowired
    StringClient stringClient;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> getAll(ServerRequest request) {
        System.out.println("StringClientHandler.getAll( ServerRequest )");

        Mono<Void> signal = stringClient.getAll();
            return ServerResponse.ok().build();
        }
    }


@Component
public class StringClient {

    private final WebClient client;

    public StringClient() {
        client = WebClient.create();
    }

    public Mono<Void> getAll() {
        System.out.println("StringClient.getAll()");

        // break chain to explicitly obtain the ClientResponse
        Mono<ClientResponse> monoCR = client.get().uri("http://localhost:8080/StringProducer/String")
                                                  .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                                  .exchange();

        // extract the Flux<String> and print to console
        Flux<String> fluxString = monoCR.flatMapMany(response -> response.bodyToFlux(String.class));
        // this statement iterates over the Flux<String> and outputs each element
        fluxString.subscribe(strVal -> System.out.println(strVal + " @ " + System.currentTimeMillis()));

        return Mono.empty();
    }
}


@Configuration
public class StringProducerRouter {
    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> demoPOJORoute(StringProducerHandler requestHandler) {
        return nest(path("/StringProducer"),
                nest(accept(APPLICATION_JSON),
                        RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.GET("/String"), requestHandler::getAll)));
    }
}


@Component
public class StringProducerHandler {

    public Mono<ServerResponse> getAll(ServerRequest request) {
        System.out.println("StringProducerHandler.getAll( ServerRequest )");

        int          listSize = 5;
        List<String> strList  = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i=0; i<listSize; i++) {
            strList.add("ListElement-" + i);         // add String value without newline termination
            strList.add("ListElement-" + i + "\n");  // add String value with    newline termination
        }

        // this statement produces the expected console output of String values
        Flux.fromIterable(strList).subscribe(System.out::println);

        return ServerResponse.ok()
                             .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                             .body(Flux.fromIterable(strList), String.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to how `org.springframework.core.codec.StringDecoder` works.

When you call `response.bodyToFlux(String.class)` the response body is transformed into a `Flux` of `String`s. The [`org.springframework.core.codec.StringDecoder`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/codec/StringDecoder.java) does the heavy lifting and has the opinion that it should split on default delimiters.

```java
List<byte[]> delimiterBytes = getDelimiterBytes(mimeType);

Flux<DataBuffer> inputFlux = Flux.from(input)
    .flatMapIterable(buffer -> splitOnDelimiter(buffer, delimiterBytes))
    .bufferUntil(buffer -> buffer == END_FRAME)
    .map(StringDecoder::joinUntilEndFrame)
    .doOnDiscard(PooledDataBuffer.class, DataBufferUtils::release);

return super.decode(inputFlux, elementType, mimeType, hints);
```

The default delimiters are `public static final List<String> DEFAULT_DELIMITERS = Arrays.asList("\r\n", "\n");`

Therefore you get:

```
ListElement-0ListElement-0 @ 1570732000374
ListElement-1ListElement-1 @ 1570732000375
...
```

instead of

```
ListElement-0 @ 1570732055461
ListElement-0 @ 1570732055461
ListElement-1 @ 1570732055462
ListElement-1 @ 1570732055462
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Does this mean that the entirety of the Flux<String> is added to the response body as a single String, and delimiters are assumed? If so, it seems a bit strange that the inverse doesn't occur when the Flux<String> is added to the ServerResponse.

Comment: Yes, this is more or less a bit inconsistent. The response is just appended to the response stream without a delimiter, which I would expect. So it is up to the user to add structure. In your case a newline or JSOn etc. However when the byte buffer is read the spring team decided to split on delimiters. Maybe @arjen-poutsma as the author remembers why.